# android add button to title bar

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-titlebar

I am trying to add a button to title bar but I couldn't succeed. I have read many articles about this but they all explain the way that doesn't fit my situation. I am using ScrollView to make the screen scrollable. but articles suggest me to use linear layout. How can I make it scrollable and have a button on the title bar?

here is my XML

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#C0C0C0" 
android:id="@+id/sw_layout">
    
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/ln_layout">
    
    <TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft=<"@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >
        .........................
        .........................
        .........................
    </TableLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And in my MainActivity, I have this code....

```
LinearLayout ln = (LinearLayout) getWindow().findViewById(R.id.ln_layout);
Button btn = new Button(this);
btn.setText("Test");
ln.addView(btn);
```

But this doesn't display anything and it doesn't give me any error. Please give me an idea. how can I add the button to title bar?

Comment: are you using theme for changing title

Comment: I am using a theme just to change the background color. thats it

Comment: I cant get you ? You cant change at all . or it does not work when u using Scrollview .then just use layour no need for scrollview on title bar

Comment: i posted example on how to create title . i was using it with android 2.3 think it will do the same for the rest

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**make title.xml and design your title : place *button* etc**

on activity

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
this.getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.title);
```

***you will access to elements on title the same way you do on main layout .using findviewbyid***

for avoiding some look problems

```
<style name="theme">
    <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/themeTitleBackground</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleSize">65dip</item>
 
</style>
  
<style name="themeTitleBackground"> 
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
       
    
</style>
```

inside androidmanifest

```
 <activity   android:theme="@style/theme"
```

Comment: It changed all the UI but I cannot see my table's content.I have to work on your code.

Comment: @ayilmaz sorry. i fixed theme style . wrongly posteed transparent . it will set titlebar for activity .

Comment: it is transparent again. content is invisible now. and the title doesnt display the button